# UIImage(named: String) or UIImage swift 4

Tags: swift, uiimageview

What way is more convenient to set image from my app assets in my app Image View? I have two ways: the first one is function  UIImage(named: String) or UIImage and both is working for me, but I want to know which one is the best ,so I can use one in the future

here is two examples

```
//  first

 let myImages1 = ["dice1", "dice2", "dice3", "dice4", "dice5", "dice6"]

 @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView1: UIImageView!

 diceImageView1.image = UIImage(named: myImages1[index1])

// second

 let myImages2 = [ image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6 ]

 @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView2: UIImageView!

 diceImageView2.image = myImages2[index2]
```

Comment: Those approaches are both bad and should be avoided.

Comment: @ElTomato Given the nature of the question I think you should provide reasons for your statement.

Comment: @rmaddy I would like them to think instead of giving them a straight answer.

Comment: @Fedir What does the API documentation say about these two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're using Images from assets catalog instead String names. It's the better way to set UIImage. But from swift 4.2 we can't use asset names anymore.
We should use image literal.
Here's the example:

```
let logoImageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()

    // Set image with image literal
    iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "feedback")
    return iv
}()
```

Look at the screenshot below.

[image]

After you've typed `Image Literal` you can double click on that and choose your image from assets catalog. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

But last time I use this lib R.swift. Get strong typed, autocompleted resources like images, fonts and segues in Swift projects.

How it looks in code:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Also you can use #color literal to use ColorSet from your Assets catalog.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension for UIImage and have static variables holding your images.

```
extension UIImage {
    static var dice1: UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: "dice1")
    }
}


let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = UIImage.dice1
```

Or you can use image literals in Xcode which are nice because you can see the actual image[image: ImageLiteral]

Comment: "Approach one is an ok approach."  Really?

Comment: Why not @El Tomato?

Comment: @Elhoej Ask Google, Yahoo or whoever about UIImage memory crash

Comment: I see, but that only occurs for huge data arrays. For 6 images its fine to use an array of image literals.